# Display Angular Material mat-error when http get request status returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm having trouble finding a way to do this. I want to display a mat-error on my input form if an http get request fails (status = 404).

I have a search form and every time a user searches for something that doesn't exist I want to display the mat-error telling the user that his search is not valid.

Here's my client side code:

rest.service.ts

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res;
  return body || { };
}

getOrder(id): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(endpoint + 'orders/' + id, httpOptions).pipe(
    map(this.extractData));
}

getReturns(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(endpoint + 'returns', httpOptions).pipe(
    map(this.extractData));
}
```

MyComponent.component.ts

Here I have the getReturnByOrderID function that checks if the response data is empty or not. If it isn't then I open a mat dialog that will lead me to some other part of my site, however, if it is empty then I'm supposed to warn the user that what he has searched for doesn't exist.

I'm also using the getErrorMessage() function to handle all the form errors.

```
private inputForm = new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(/^\d+$/)]);

constructor(public rest: RestService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

getReturnByOrderId(value) {
  if (value.length > 0) {
    this.rest.getOrder(value).subscribe((data: {}) => {
      if (Object.entries(data).length !== 0) {
        this.openDialog(data);
      } else {
        //if 404, do something here
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.rest.getReturns().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.returns = data;
    });
  }
}

openDialog(el) {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
    width: '70%',
    data: el
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
  });
}

getErrorMessage() {
  return this.inputForm.hasError('pattern') ? 'Insert numeric value!' : '';
  // if the get request fails I'd have a message here saying "The order you searched for doesn't exist!"
}
```

MyComponent.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
      <input matInput class="search-input" placeholder="Search" [formControl]="inputForm" #searchInput>
      <mat-error *ngIf="inputForm?.invalid">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>
      <mat-hint>Insert an order ID.</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <span matSuffix>
      <button mat-raised-button class="search-btn" color="accent" [disabled]="inputForm?.invalid" (click)="getReturnByOrderId(searchInput.value)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if my server side code would be usefull, if anyone needs it I'll edit my question...

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: you need to write a error block to handle 404 response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the server returns 404 status code, in this case, your subscribe block won't execute. so your need to write error block where you can handle 404 error and set form as invalid like below.

```
getReturnByOrderId(value) {
  if (value.length > 0) {
    this.rest.getOrder(value).subscribe((data: {}) => {
      if (Object.entries(data).length !== 0) {
        this.openDialog(data);
      } else {
         // if data is empty show 
        this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
      }
    }, error => {
        //when 404 error 
        this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });

    });
  } else {
    this.rest.getReturns().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.returns = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I'm glad, I could help!